# Python2 comparing tuple and int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, comparison, python-2.x

I'm currently porting some Python2 code to Python3, and I've encountered this little gem:

```
v = (1, )
if v < 1:
    pass
```

Now, in Python3 it throws an error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'.
```

Which is fine, since you cannot compare tuples and integers. But in Python2 this is allowed:

```
>>> (1, ) < 1
    False
```

I've googled, but can't find an example of how this comparison works. How/why does the above example evaluate to `False`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in behavior is described in the docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result). Furthermore, some types (for example, file objects) support only a degenerate notion of comparison where any two objects of that type are unequal. Again, such objects are ordered arbitrarily but consistently. The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number.

---

As you already noticed, comparing tuples and integers no longer work in Python 3, due to some changes in the comparison mechanics:

https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

> - The ordering comparison operators (<, <=, >=, >) raise a TypeError exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering. Thus, expressions like 1 < '', 0 > None or len <= len are no longer valid, and e.g. None < None raises TypeError instead of returning False. A corollary is that sorting a heterogeneous list no longer makes sense – all the elements must be comparable to each other. Note that this does not apply to the == and != operators: objects of different incomparable types always compare unequal to each other.
> - builtin.sorted() and list.sort() no longer accept the cmp argument providing a comparison function. Use the key argument instead. N.B. the key and reverse arguments are now “keyword-only”.
> - The cmp() function should be treated as gone, and the **cmp**() special method is no longer supported. Use **lt**() for sorting, **eq**() with **hash**(), and other rich comparisons as needed. (If you really need the cmp() functionality, you could use the expression (a > b) - (a < b) as the equivalent for cmp(a, b).)

Comment: Could be worth adding the relevant section of the [Whats new in python3 page](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons)